# Doubt related to application of FFT

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

I found this formula in a paper : http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=5655742

could someone explain the meaning of "j is frequency sample in the highlighted part.(since frequency limits have defined earlier)

[image]

Comment: Isn't it wonderful when electrical engineers in general and DSP folks in particular don't worry about using $j$ as an integer index instead of relegating it to representing one of the square roots of -1?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I don't really see a problem with that. It's usually obvious from context, and I prefer $i$ for the imaginary unit anyway. But I guess that collided with the use of that same symbol fro the current density. In any case, any reasonably broad field of applied mathematics will have several instances of overloaded symbols. There's not much you can do about it. And what's more annoying, having to learn more symbols from foreign languages or to just use your brain to recognise the context?